# Why is this number the smallest positive normalised binary value?

Tags: binary, floating-point

In the AQA A2 Computing textbook (Bond and Langfield, 2009), they say that this number is the smallest positive normalised value, given a 10 bit mantissa and a 6 bit exponent:

```
Mantissa: 0.1000 00000
Exponent: 100000
```

I don't understand why this is the case. I would have thought that having a mantissa of 0.000000001 would result in the smallest positive value. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Does [this page](http://www.teach-ict.com/as_as_computing/ocr/H447/F453/3_3_4/floating_point/miniweb/pg10.htm) help?

Comment: Not really, I still don't understand.

Comment: I don't know AQA but in general the difference between normalised and denormalised numbers in floating point theory is that you normalise by making the mantissa be large; a mantissa like 0.00001 is by definition denormal.  Look at the example near the bottom of that page.  (I would give an answer but like I say I don't know AQA; I certainly know a ton about IEEE-754 though! :) )

Comment: We haven't really studied IEEE and Minifloat, just floating point :). But okay, I think that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

On the AQA and Cambridge syllabuses, the text books state that normalized numbers must begin with either **10** (negative) or **01** (positive) in order to guarantee the maximum accuracy of the mantissa and is called **normalised float form**. This is not the case in IEEE but neither exam boards use IEEE.

The **twos compliment** version of **the exponent** is read like this:
-127 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 in terms of powers eg the MSB is a negative power. There is no possible arrangement of bit s that can be lower than -127 so 100000000 is the smallest exponent as it represents -127 or 2 to the power -127. If you place a one bit anywhere else it increases the number in twos compliment.

**Now the mantissa:** your mantissa is **not in normal form** as it begins with **00** thus breaking the rule of beginning with **01 or 10**.The first positive mantissa that follows this rule is 0.100000000.Which is approximately 1 * 2 to power -127.